# What causes different results by interchanging the tensors in an Eigen::Tensor contraction?

Tags: python, c++, eigen, tensor, numpy-einsum

I am working on a C++ library that relies on tensor contractions. I won't post the full application here, but I've distilled it down to the following.

We define a toy rank-4 tensor, which is nothing but (0, 1, ..., 15) reshaped:

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 4> T (2, 2, 2, 2);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            for (size_t l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                T(i, j, k, l) = l + 2 * k + 4 * j + 8 * i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a rank-2 tensor to contract with, which is nothing but (1, 2, 3, 4) reshaped:

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> A (2, 2);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        A(i, j) = 1 + j + 2 * i;
    }
}
```

To contract two tensors in Eigen, we have to specify a contraction pair. Our goal is to contract the first two indices of the tensors, as in `T(ijkl)*A(ib)=M(bjkl)`. With my current understanding of the Tensor module in Eigen, we will write the contraction pair as

```
Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<int>, 1> contraction_pair = {Eigen::IndexPair<int>(0, 0)};
```

However, I think it should be possible to use the exact same contraction pair to perform the contraction `A(ib)*T(ijkl)=N(bjkl)`. Unfortunately, this is not the case, and the elements of `M` are

```
0 0 0 0  24
0 0 0 1  32
0 0 1 0  28
0 0 1 1  38
0 1 0 0  32
0 1 0 1  44
0 1 1 0  36
0 1 1 1  50
1 0 0 0  40
1 0 0 1  56
1 0 1 0  44
1 0 1 1  62
1 1 0 0  48
1 1 0 1  68
1 1 1 0  52
1 1 1 1  74
```

while these of `N` are

```
0 0 0 0  24
0 0 0 1  28
0 0 1 0  32
0 0 1 1  36
0 1 0 0  40
0 1 0 1  44
0 1 1 0  48
0 1 1 1  52
1 0 0 0  32
1 0 0 1  38
1 0 1 0  44
1 0 1 1  50
1 1 0 0  56
1 1 0 1  62
1 1 1 0  68
1 1 1 1  74
```

I have tested the same toy tensors in numpy, using einsum:

```
T = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)
A = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)

contraction1 = np.einsum('ijkl,ia->ajkl', integrals, C)
contraction2 = np.einsum('ia,ijkl->ajkl', C, integrals)
```

and both `contraction1` and `contraction2` are

```
0   0   0   0   24
0   0   0   1   28
0   0   1   0   32
0   0   1   1   36
0   1   0   0   40
0   1   0   1   44
0   1   1   0   48
0   1   1   1   52
1   0   0   0   32
1   0   0   1   38
1   0   1   0   44
1   0   1   1   50
1   1   0   0   56
1   1   0   1   62
1   1   1   0   68
1   1   1   1   74
```

which coincide with the case `A(ib)*T(ijkl)=N(bjkl)` in Eigen. What causes Eigen to not give the same result in both cases?

Comment: I may be totally wrong here, but if you only specify the axes to contract then it's not clear which order the remaining axes should appear in. In the numpy example you completely specify this by  the first argument. Maybe Eigen keeps them in the order first tensor's surviving axes first, then second tensor's surviving axes?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks for giving that insightful answer. If we shuffle `M`'s axes as `M.shuffle(Eigen::array<int, 4> {3, 0, 1, 2})`, then we get exactly `N` back, as can be verified by `(M_shuffled == N).all()` which leads to the value 1, meaning that they are element-wise equal. Could you provide your comment (maybe including this comment as well?) as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Will do, give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Eigen` interface appears to take only the contraction axes for specification. It therefore has to decide itself how to arrange the non-contracted axes. The obvious way would be to keep the original axes in order, first the first argument's then second's.

To confirm this we can either

- use `np.einsum` specifying different output layouts and compare to the output of `Eigen`:

.

```
import numpy as np

T = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)
A = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)

print(np.einsum('ijkl,ia->ajkl', T, A))
# [[[[24 28]
#    [32 36]]

#   [[40 44]
#    [48 52]]]


#  [[[32 38]
#    [44 50]]

#   [[56 62]
#    [68 74]]]]

print(np.einsum('ijkl,ia->jkla', T, A))
# [[[[24 32]
#    [28 38]]

#   [[32 44]
#    [36 50]]]


#  [[[40 56]
#    [44 62]]

#   [[48 68]
#    [52 74]]]]
```

- or shuffle directly in `Eigen` (thanks @lelemmen):

.

```
M.shuffle(Eigen::array<int, 4> {3, 0, 1, 2})
(M_shuffled == N).all()

# 1
```

Comment: I took the liberty to create a Gist out of this, combining the question and this accepted answer: https://gist.github.com/lelemmen/d01a32387363376d00191d10208a5440.